# Unknown Device USB Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, usb

Everytime I plug in any USB drive on my computer on a Windows 7 machine, I get this error: `Unknown Device` with `Code 43`. I have tried many solutions such as searching for missing drivers and installing them but unfortunately none of them worked for me!

Any help will be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Open Computer Management console and look under Device Manager. Right click the "Unknown device" and select "Properties". There should be done error text. Send us this. Also, in the same window is an advanced tab: there should be a "hardware id" or similar that tells us what the device is our easier to identify.

Comment: The error message you asked for is: `Windows has stopped this device because it has reported problems. (Code 43)` and the hardware ID says: `USB\UNKNOWN`.

Comment: Do other USB devices (not mass storage devices) work when you plug them in? Do your devices work in other computers? You may want to reset the on-board USB hub to see if that makes a difference. Resetting normally fixes over-current problems, though, so don't expect much

Comment: Yes it does work on other computers, besides I have tried many USB drives on my computer but the error always persists, which drives me crazy!

Comment: I'm going to guess you may have a problem with the USB hub. Is it all USB ports that result in the error?

Comment: I have tried it on all USB ports of my computer but still does not function.

Answer (score 0):

Grabbed this from the Windows website:

```
This issue can be caused if any of the following situations exist:
The currently loaded USB driver has become unstable or corrupt
Your PC requires an update for issues that may conflict with a USB external hard drive and Windows
Windows may be missing other important updates hardware or software issues
Your USB controllers may have become unstable or corrupt
Your external drive may be entering selective suspend
Your PC motherboard may need updated drivers
```

Probability suggests it is a driver issue. Now, to get the right drivers usually I would need to find out a whole range of information, however, to make both of our lives easier, download and install [SlimDrivers](http://slimdrivers.en.softonic.com/.) This utility program will scan your pc, download and install drivers for you!

You will have to download and install one driver at a time (you probably will have a range of drivers out of date, but make sure you update the motherboard drivers and then try again.

Comment: I have tried `SlimDrivers`and also `DriversFinder`but the errors always persists!

Comment: @WaiylKarim are you using a laptop or desktop?

Comment: Desktop HP xw8400 WorkStation

Comment: @WaiylKarim Ok lets try another thing (if you haven't already). Try shutting down your PC, unplug power and hold the power button (get rid of all current). Then leave for few mins, then plugin and and try again

Comment: @WaiylKarim Once you tried step above try this. Switch on, press F10 to get into BIOS, go to Storage tab, go to Boot Order, and make sure USB Device is not grayed out.  You use F5 key in that section of BIOS to toggle back and forth from enabled to disabled once you have highlighted the selection.  Don't forget to save on the way out of BIOS.
 
The use of USB devices in BIOS related activities for these workstations wants to be from cold boots...[More here](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/Workstations-z-series-xw-series/Hp-Xw8400-boot-to-USB-issues/td-p/6219615)

Comment: I have tried to remove the bios battery for 5 minutes but it didn't work for me. Anyways, I am gonna try what asked me to now and get back to you in a few minutes.

Comment: @WaiylKarim sorry to hear that didn't work. Could always be a motherboard defect (which I don't think it is), but you might have to get in touch with Dell and see if they can provide you with a solution

Comment: Unfortunately nothing worked, so I think I am going to contact HP. Thank you buddy!

Comment: @WaiylKarim dang it. Thats the problem with computers, they can go wrong and can be a b**** to solve. Defitnetly worth contacting them and explain that you've tried a number of things without luck. As a last resort (after you spoke to dell), maybe consider re-installing a fresh copy of windows. Good luck :)

Comment: That's it man. I have read some articles saying that I have to upgrade my computer's mothership, but I don't know what does this even mean!

Comment: People on computing articles like the complicate things! Hopefully, Dell will give you a link an instructions on how to download/reinstall the drivers for the motherboard directly in BIOS (which is what i suspect the issue is). I think by `upgrade my computers mothership` means upgrade the whole computer!

Comment: I believe so. I'm gonna email them now. And thank for your help man, appreciate it!

Comment: @WaiylKarim Best of luck! I hope dell sort it once and for all! If you're happy with the answer, don't forget to accept (select the tick)